# "Guten" instead of "Guten Appetit"?

Tags: colloquial

Am I going insane, or are people just saying "Guten" whenever I whip out food?

To be more specific:

1. Do people say "Guten" as an abbreviation for "Guten Appetit"?
2. If yes, is it interchangeable with Guten Appetit or situational?
3. If yes, can I use it for other phrases starting with "Gut"? Like "Guten Morgen" or "Gute Besserung"?

Context: Northeastern Baden-Württemberg, southwestern Germany.

Comment: Haven’t you ever greeted someone with just “morning”? What does it mean? Are you trying to inform them of the approximate time of day, or is it an accepted contraction for “I wish you a very pleasant morning, good sir”? Btw, “ein Guten” is much more familiar, than simply “Guten”.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. yes, you can use it as a replacement for "Guten Appetit"
2. i would not recommend using it unless you are in a loose colloquial situation (e.g. friends and colleagues), where etique doesnt matter and everybody knows what you are trying to convey anyway. If you want to be polite, then use the complete term.
3. In my experience "Guten Morgen" can also be abbreviated. But the same reservations apply.

   > Guude (langgezogen gesprochen) ist typisch für Hessen.[1](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/gude--guten-morgen-)

   When it comes to "Guten Besserung", people usually try to take at least make the effort of using the whole phrase to give their best wishes.

Depending on region it could also be:
"Gute", "Gude", "N'Guten", "(schönen) juten (Tach) (auch)", "Mahlzeit", "Moin", "Morgje", etc.

[image: Grußformelkarte]

[Grußformeln im deutschsprachigen Raum](https://kristianmitk.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/grusformeln-im-deutschsprachigen-raum/)

Comment: Zur Karte: Hier werden die Sie- und die Du-Form von gleichen Grüßen als verschiedene Grüße dargestellt. »Griaß Eana« heißt auf Hochdeutsch *»(ich) begrüße Sie«* (sowohl Singular als auch Plural) und »Griaß di« ist *»(ich) begrüße dich«*. »Griaß enk« ist der Plural der Du-Form (*»(ich) begrüße euch«*) Das ist in Wahrheit alles ein und derselbe Gruß. Auch auffallend: Laut dieser Karte grüßt man sich in Österreich und in Südtirol gar nicht. Das gilt auch für den Osten Deutschlands

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: das ist richtig, auch berlin wird auf der Karte nicht aufgeführt. Ich könnte mir auch vorstellen, dass die geographischen Grenzen sich nicht ebenso hart in der Sprache niederschlagen. Was diese Karte allerdings kann, ist eine grobe Ahnung davon vermitteln, dass es unterschiedliche Umgangsformen gibt. Für alles andere hilft vielleicht auch der verlinkte Blogeintrag weiter.

Answer (score 0):

BestGuess' circumscription *"in a loose colloquial situation"* is very diplomatic. :-) I consider *Guten* plebby. *Guten Appetit* is neither a long nor a grammatically intricate construction. People who feel the need to reduce it to one word, well, the next step is ointing. Thus I support NextGuess' reccommendation not to use it. It's a matter of style, niveau, ...

*Gute Verbesserung* doesn't exist, it's *Gute Besserung*. ;-) It cannot be reduced to *Gute*. But as *Guten* instead of *Guten Appetit* attracts your negative attention, you wouldn't do it anyway. You're on the right side. :-))

Comment: Well, i always considered the "Morje" that i received from my colleagues in hessia as pretty sympathetic. I would not use it in a job interview or when talking to a policeman after during a traffic check, but for people you frequently see, it is alright in my book.

Comment: Well I'm a college student so I don't quite identify with high culture ^^ but I even occasionally heard it from work colleges or even my boss, so it might just be considered sympathetic here, like BestGuess pointed out. And thanks for the correction! I edited it in.